# How to convert a list to dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have lists like this:

```
['7801234567', 'Robert Post', '66 Hinton Road']
['7809876543', 'Farrukh Ahmed', '101 Edson Crest']
['7803214567', 'Md Toukir Imam', '34 Sherwood Park Avenue']
['7807890123', 'Elham Ahmadi', '8 Devon Place']
['7808907654', 'Rong Feng', '32 Spruce Street']
['7801236789', 'Nazanin Tahmasebi', '98 Albert Avenue']
['7804321098', 'Sayem Mohammad Siam', '56 Stony Place']
['7808765432', 'Amir Hossein Faghih Dinevari', '45 Beautiful Street']
```

How should I convert them to dictionaries with keys named: `'tel'`, `'name'`, and`'address'`?

Comment: ....what should the dictionary look like? Can you be more explicit?

Comment: In addition to what @juanpa.arrivillaga said, do you want a list of dictionaries?

Comment: it should be like:

Comment: {'tel': '7808765432', 'name': 'Amir Hossein Faghih Dinevari', 'address': '45 Beautiful Street'}

Comment: but I want to convert all the lists to this(mentioned below) in the same time. how should I do it?

Comment: @AustinJin Don't you know basic looping principles?

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip` to associate the keys with their values by index

```
keys = ('tel', 'name', 'address')
values = ['7801234567', 'Robert Post', '66 Hinton Road']

d = dict(zip(keys, values))
# {'tel': '7801234567', 'name': 'Robert Post', 'address': '66 Hinton Road'}
```

Edit:

Obviously, you can use this technique to create more complex structures.

```
info = [['7801234567', 'Robert Post', '66 Hinton Road'],
        ['7809876543', 'Farrukh Ahmed', '101 Edson Crest'],
        ['7803214567', 'Md Toukir Imam', '34 Sherwood Park Avenue'],
        ['7807890123', 'Elham Ahmadi', '8 Devon Place'],
        ['7808907654', 'Rong Feng', '32 Spruce Street'],
        ['7801236789', 'Nazanin Tahmasebi', '98 Albert Avenue'],
        ['7804321098', 'Sayem Mohammad Siam', '56 Stony Place'], 
        ['7808765432', 'Amir Hossein Faghih Dinevari', '45 Beautiful Street']]
keys = ('tel', 'name', 'address')

dictionaries = [dict(zip(keys, values)) for values in info]
```

The `[_ for _ in _]` is called a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

Comment: it works. but I have lots of lists. if I all assign them to 'd', then it will have the last result, however I want all of them. how should I do it?

Comment: Why not a list of dicts?

Answer (score 1):

We assume the data are given as:

```
info_row = [['7801234567', 'Robert Post', '66 Hinton Road'],
 ['7809876543', 'Farrukh Ahmed', '101 Edson Crest'],
 ['7803214567', 'Md Toukir Imam', '34 Sherwood Park Avenue'],
 ...,
]
```

and

```
info_type = ['tel', 'name', 'address']
```

We could first write a function to convert each "row" list.

```
def convert_row(row_name, row_content):
    d = dict()
    for i, j in enumerate(row_name):
        d[j] = row_content[i]
    return d
```

Then, we can use list comprehension to apply such function to the whole list of list.

```
expected_result = [convert_row(info_type, r) for r in info_row]
```

As another answer has pointed out, we can make use of `zip`. Using built-in routines is more than encouraged in most cases. So it is better to type

```
expected_result = [dict(zip(info_type, r)) for r in info_row]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a list comprehension:

```
data = [['7801234567', 'Robert Post', '66 Hinton Road'],
        ['7809876543', 'Farrukh Ahmed', '101 Edson Crest'],
        ['7803214567', 'Md Toukir Imam', '34 Sherwood Park Avenue'],
        ['7807890123', 'Elham Ahmadi', '8 Devon Place'],
        ['7808907654', 'Rong Feng', '32 Spruce Street'],
        ['7801236789', 'Nazanin Tahmasebi', '98 Albert Avenue'],
        ['7804321098', 'Sayem Mohammad Siam', '56 Stony Place'],
        ['7808765432', 'Amir Hossein Faghih Dinevari', '45 Beautiful Street']]

new_data = [{'tel': tel, 'name': name, 'address': address} for tel, name, address in data]

print(new_data)
```

Which Outputs:

```
[{'tel': '7801234567', 'name': 'Robert Post', 'address': '66 Hinton Road'}, {'tel': '7809876543', 'name': 'Farrukh Ahmed', 'address': '101 Edson Crest'}, {'tel': '7803214567', 'name': 'Md Toukir Imam', 'address': '34 Sherwood Park Avenue'}, {'tel': '7807890123', 'name': 'Elham Ahmadi', 'address': '8 Devon Place'}, {'tel': '7808907654', 'name': 'Rong Feng', 'address': '32 Spruce Street'}, {'tel': '7801236789', 'name': 'Nazanin Tahmasebi', 'address': '98 Albert Avenue'}, {'tel': '7804321098', 'name': 'Sayem Mohammad Siam', 'address': '56 Stony Place'}, {'tel': '7808765432', 'name': 'Amir Hossein Faghih Dinevari', 'address': '45 Beautiful Street'}]
```